# CS50 speller: Unload executes 80,000,000+ frees

Tags: c, cs50

This is pset 5 in Harvard's CS50. It consists mainly of loading the dictionary, checking whether each word in the chosen text is found within the loaded dictionary and then unloading (freeing all of the allocated memory).
All the other functions work but when it comes to unload it just executes, as stated, 80,000,000+ frees, whilst in the program there is just 143,094 mallocs, I am a newbie so this is mindblowing for me. Below are the relevant functions for unload.

**Edit (1):** Here is some context regarding the variable *hashtable*.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH+2];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

node *hashtable[264636] = { NULL };
```

I initialize each element to NULL so that in unload I can easily skip the index values for which no key was generated in the hash function.

```
//LOAD FUNCTION: Loads the dictionary into a hash table. Djb2 function used. 

bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }
    opntr = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    while (fscanf(opntr, "%s", WORD) != EOF)
    {
        wnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (wnode == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(wnode->word, WORD);
        wnode->next = head; 
        head = wnode; 
        unsigned long key = hash(wnode->word);
        hashtable[key] = wnode;
        wnode = wnode->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
// Checks whether the input word is somewhere within the dictionary

bool check(const char *word)
{
    char dword[strlen(word) + 1];
    strcpy(dword, word);
    for (int c = 0; c < strlen(dword); c++)
    {
        dword[c] = tolower(dword[c]);
    }
    int key_w;
    key_w = hash(dword);
    node *cursor = hashtable[key_w];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(cursor->word, dword) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
// Unloads memory allocated (?) to store the dictionary

bool unload(void)
{
    for (int in = 0; in < 264636; in++)
    {
        node *fhead = hashtable[in];             
        while (fhead != NULL)
        {
            node *fcursor = fhead->next;
            free(fhead);
            fhead = fcursor;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is `hashtable`? Show a [mcve]. Emphasis on **complete**.

Comment: Exactly where does the "80,000,000" number come from?

Comment: Did you know that it's a waste of time and CPU cycles to manually `free` everything right before exiting?  The operating system is going to deallocate all of the memory assigned to your program anyway, so all the bookkeeping work is wasted.

Comment: @zwol It's a good habit to clean up the mess after yourself. Once one learned it they can think when to apply or not this skill. But in this specific case it might have pointed to some bug.

Comment: That only 143k `malloc`s are performed is excellent justification for saying that at most that many `free`s ***should*** be performed, but it's no justification at all for believing that no more *will* be performed.  The latter is determined by your program, and the discrepancy is indeed something to worry about.  It means your program is wrong.

Comment: I can see what you've done. but what are you trying to do?  hint: the structure built by `load()` is totally wrong. the definition of `node` could be useful too.

Comment: @Jasen I have thought about it, but when I run it with check50, which submits the program to some tests, it works fine until unload messes it up, that's why I didn't look further into the other functions. Could you please point the main problem?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield 
It comes from running valgrind:
==9416== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9416==     in use at exit: 1,240 bytes in 13 blocks
==9416==   total heap usage: 143,094 allocs, 85,679,521 frees, 8,014,288 bytes allocated

Comment: the main error is that load() is building the wrong structure.  what structure do you think load() should be building?

Comment: @Jasen I intend to hash each word in the dictionary and then append it to the beginning of the linked list originated by the corresponding element in the node pointer to the hashtable array.

Comment: where does `wnode->next` point?  where should it point?

Comment: @Jasen I guess I realize the problem now that I tried explaining what it does, I believe the way in which I update the node is just wrong, as it causes **all** the elements of the hashtable array to be connected as some large linked list, hence losing the intended structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody finds it helpful, the problem was within the load function. The nodes malloced were updated wrongfully so that the elements of the hashtable array weren't independent linked lists and I was unnecessarily using a head node to point to the first element of the list each time we wanted to add a node. Instead, to add a new node to its corresponding element in the hashtable array, we use the element itself as the head of the linked list and we arrange it so that it points to each node added, thus succesfully keeping track of the beginning of the linked list. Each element in the hashtable is initially pointing to NULL so that we can find the end of each linked list.

```
int null()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 264636; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    opntr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    while (fscanf(opntr, "%s", WORD) != EOF)
    {
        wnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (wnode == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(wnode->word, WORD);
        unsigned long key = hash(wnode->word);
        wnode->next = hashtable[key]; 
        hashtable[key] = wnode; 
    }
    return true;
}
```